# Sentence processing in Python

Tags: python, file, text, nltk

I have a file with such data:

```
Sentence[0].Sentence[1].Sentence[2].'/n'
Sentence[0].Sentence[1].Sentence[2].'/n'
Sentence[0].Sentence[1].Sentence[2].'/n'
```

What I want to print out are all Sentences0. This is what I have done, but it prints out a blank list.

```
from nltk import *
import codecs
f=codecs.open('topon.txt','r+','cp1251')
text = f.readlines()
first=[sentence for sentence in text if re.findall('\.\n^Abc',sentence)]
print first
```

Comment: Is this homework, or do you have multiple accounts? [This exact post just showed up, barely minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19693087/198633)

Comment: Since you're reading individual lines, your regexp will never succeed: It's looking for a newline in the middle of a string. And why are you searching for `Abc` when you say you want the first of the three sentences? Please clarify your task.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I know about that post. It was created coz i couldn't post a question from my own account. When i succeed, it was deleted.

Comment: @alexis, actually I have a great amount of text with paragraphs separated with new lines. And I need to print out only first sentences of each paragraph.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need NLTK for this (nor are you using it). Unless I misunderstand the question, this should do the trick:

```
with open('topon.txt') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    print line.split('.', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @inspectorG4dget 's answer, you can do it by regexes:

```
from nltk import *
import codecs

f = codecs.open('a.txt', 'r+', 'cp1251')
text = f.readlines()
print [re.findall('^[^.]+', sentence) for sentence in text]
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a paragraph at periods works only if every sentence ends with a period, and periods are used for nothing else. If you have a lot of real text, neither of these is even close to true. Abbreviations, questions? exclamations! etc. will trip you up a lot. So, use the tool that the nltk provides for this purpose: the function `sent_tokenize()`. It's not perfect, but it's a whole lot better than looking for periods. If `text` is your list of paragraphs, you use it like this:

```
first = [ ]
for par in text:
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(par)
    first.append(sentences[0])
```

You could fold the above into a list comprehension, but it's not going to be very readable...